# How do you make a server side request in Meteor to fetch a list of a user's FB friends?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, meteor, facebook-javascript-sdk

On the server side of my meteor application, I am trying to request a list of a user's FB friends, but I am struggling to find any resources on how to do this. I've found the following resources online and see that there is no standard way to do this:

- [Fetching Facebook Friends List with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950088/fetching-facebook-friends-list-with-meteor)
- http://www.andrehonsberg.com/article/facebook-graph-api-meteor-js
- [Meteor: Facebook basic API call error: access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423346/meteor-facebook-basic-api-call-error-access-token)
- [Meteor how to get access to Facebook Graph Api for both Server and Client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30911944/meteor-how-to-get-access-to-facebook-graph-api-for-both-server-and-client-side)

Can anyone provide an example of client and server side js code in Meteor working together to achieve this goal of getting a list of a user's facebook friends?

Comment: It is no longer possible to fetch a full list of a user's friends via the Graph API. The API now only returns friends who have also authorized your application (usually a vanishingly small proportion).

Comment: @ceejayoz can you share what meteor packages you have used to make a server side call to the Graph API?

Comment: Anything that can make a HTTP request will suffice.